# Splitting a String which has longitude and latitude points

Tags: java, android, split, kml

I have a kmlLayer which has several placemarkers on it. I want to iterate through these placemarkers and retrieve their coordinates so as to find the distance from my location to those points and only set the markers in a certain distance visible. 
I have the following code

```
 for (KmlPlacemark placemark: layer.getPlacemarks()) {
            String s = ("placemarks",placemark.getGeometry()..getGeometryObject().toString());
```

String s has the following format:
lat/lng: (55.94569390835889,-3.190410055779333)
I want to extract the two coordinated from it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can guarantee that the String to parse is always defined in a canonical way, so that is defined as  lat+long ALWAYS, then using regex will be the easiest way:

## Example:

```
 String latLong = "lat/lng: (55.94569390835889,-3.190410055779333)";
 Pattern patte = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?");
 Matcher matcher = patte.matcher(latLong);
 while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group()));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you don't want to use Regex, do it by hands. First remove anything before "("  and after ")"

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("(")+1,s.indexOf(")")); //this will get you "55...,-3.19..."
```

And then split it by ",".

```
String[] strngs = s.split(",");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(strings[0]);
double lon = Double.parseDouble(string[1]);
```